# iOS, java ee: aes encryption, bytes changing after being send

Tags: java, ios, jakarta-ee, encryption, aes

Im trying to send aes encrypted data to a javaee server and getting different bytes after sending it. When I encrypt the same string with the same key on ios and javaee I get the same bytes, but when I send the encrypted bytes to the server they are slightly off. Here are my encryption methods....

***** iOS AES ENCRYPTION *****

```
 - (NSData*)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString*)key {
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding/*NSUTF8StringEncoding*/];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

   size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
   void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);


   size_t numBytesEncrypted    = 0;
   CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,

                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,

                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {


        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

   free(buffer); //free the buffer;
   return nil;
}
```

this is the 'AESAdditions' example for NSData. so my implementation of this is...

```
NSData *encryptedData = [self encryptString:@"test" withKey:@"0123456789abcdef"];
```

where 'encryptString:withKey:' is....

```
- (NSData*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
}
```

and this is returning the bytes 
     (d24374ca 9c7adedd 26d3d285 8d42e69c)

I then set this as the body for url request as such....

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com"]];
[request setHTTPBody:encryptedData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *errro;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&errro];
```

My java aes encryption method is...

```
public byte[] AESencrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,ivParameterSpec/*new IvParameterSpec(INITIALIZATIO_VECTOR.getBytes("UTF-8"))*/);

    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

  }
```

and my implementation of this is...

```
byte[] encryptedString = AESencrypt("test", "0123456789abcdef");
```

and the outcome of this is (d24374ca 9c7adedd 26d3d285 8d42e69c)
the same as the iphone version...

BUT when I retrieve the body of the url request in javaee I get slightly different bytes. The way I get the bytes is such...

*** this is being done in the doGet method ***

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();    

body = reader.readLine();
byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
```

then when I print out the bytes I get d24374ca    3f7adedd    26d3d23f    3f42e63f ... (different from iPhone and javaee)

so to recap...

iPhone AES-encrypted bytes: d24374ca    9c7adedd    26d3d285    8d42e69c

javaee encrypted bytes: d24374ca    9c7adedd    26d3d285    8d42e69c

transmitted bytes: d24374ca    3f7adedd    26d3d23f    3f42e63f

what am I doing wrong that the bytes get altered when I send them to the javaee server?

Thanks for the help

*** UPDATE ***

I have been messing around with it some more and noticed when I remove the "+1" from the ios encryption(on the second line), the bytes dont change when the get to the server... but the result is different and I cant seem to get the same result on the server side :/ .... Maybe this will help?

Comment: Using a hard-coded IV defeats the purpose of CBC and leaves you vulnerable.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-11-18/common-crypto-pitfalls/#don-39-t-reuse-ivs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINALLY!!!!**

I found the answer!! So the way I was doing the encryption was correct, the problem was getting the body of the request.

Before I was doing...

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();    
body = reader.readLine();
byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
```

using 'getReader()' is what was causing the problem. So instead of the above code I used the code...

```
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = getBytesFromInputStream(is);
```

where 'getBytesFromInputStream' is ...

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFFF];

        for (int len; (len = is.read(buffer)) != -1;)
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);

        os.flush();

        return os.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

From there I got the same bytes as what I send to the server. I think I read somewhere that 'getReader()' changes some padding characters or something, and I think thats why when I would get rid of the '+1', that the bytes wouldn't change...

So in conclusion...

**DONT NOT USE**

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
body = reader.readLine();
byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
```

**USE INSTEAD**

```
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = getBytesFromInputStream(is);
```

(when retrieving a padded encryption string)

hopefully this helps people out with the same problem...

Comment: If anyone was wonder, this does hold true for returning encrypted data. DONT USE  response.getWriter()   instead USE response.getOutputStream()